Does the definition of Lie groups rely on invariance of domain?
I have some confusion over what we can say for certainty about the dimensions of a manifold or product of manifolds, without directly applying invariance of domain/dimension. In the definition of a Lie group, product manifolds are directly involved, and I'm not sure if I actually need that theorem to conclude the tangent of product manifold is isomorphic to the product (direct sum) of the tangents. Thanks in advance.

What definitions are you talking about? Please don't make us guess. In any case, you do not need invariance of domain to show that the tangent bundle of a product is the product of tangent bundles.

The definition of a Lie group makes no reference to dimension, or tangent spaces, or invariance of domain. Read it carefully. All you need is a smooth manifold $G$ and a smooth map $m : G \times G \to G$ satisfying certain conditions. The definition of a smooth map refers to how $m$ behaves in local coordinates, and this again makes no reference to dimension, or tangent spaces, or invariance of domain.
In local coordinates $m$ is locally (say at the origin) some smooth function $m : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ - now we finally use the concept of dimension, but all we really need here is that if $U$ is an open subset of $G$ then $U \times U$ is an open subset of $G \times G$, and this follows directly from the definition of the product topology. Smoothness can be defined by repeatedly taking partial derivatives and you don't need to know what tangent spaces are to define it.
None of this requires invariance of domain. Without invariance of domain it might be the case that $m$ has some other representation in local coordinates with a different number of dimensions on either side, but that doesn't affect the definition. It might make you worry about whether the definition of a smooth map is independent of the choice of local coordinates, but the definition of a smooth manifold is exactly designed to make this true.
All of this should be clarified by looking at any nontrivial examples. The basic interesting example of a Lie group is the group $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ of invertible $n \times n$ real matrices. This is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ so it inherits a smooth structure from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, and multiplication is a polynomial function, and polynomials are smooth. Inversion is a rational function and rational functions are also smooth. There is again no need to discuss tangent spaces or invariance of domain here.

Thanks a lot. I always thought we need to first prove "if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are smooth manifolds then $T_{(p,q)}M_1\times M_2 \simeq T_p M_1 \times T_q M_2$" before we can even claim $M_1\times M_2$ is a smooth manifold. And when doing so, came my confusion.

@user760 but the definition of a smooth manifold doesn't mention tangent spaces. At least, not any definition I'm familiar with. Instead the tangent space is a result of the differentiable structure. So all you would need to show is that a product manifold has a naturally defined smooth atlas (if we really wanted to go to that trouble), no?

@Callum I realized my mistake. It seems I got all these concepts (and who comes before whom) mixed up.

@user760: no, you don't need that, but that is also straightforward to prove without invariance of domain. Moreover once you prove that the tangent spaces of a smooth $n$-manifold are $n$-dimensional "smooth invariance of domain" (that if two smooth manifolds are diffeomorphic, or even locally diffeomorphic, then they have the same dimension) quickly follows, it is much easier than the topological version.
